# Programmatically select a checkbox of a filter

Tags: algolia

I am using Algolia on my wordpress website.  I've made a search results page which uses most of the standard, built-in aloglia features.  What I am trying to do is when someone types in a keyword and if it matches one of my tags, categories, related topic types, I want it to have that topic type selected.  I need to do this programmatically.  I'd imagine i could do this with javascript, but when i tried this it didnt take effect.

```
jQuery('#qry-<?php // echo $active_query_term_slug; ?>').attr('checked', true);
```

I also tried:

```
helper.on('result', function(result) {
    result.hits.forEach( (hit) =>
         jQuery('#qry-<?php // echo $active_query_term_slug; ?>').attr('checked', true);
     )
});
```

I should add that I have added an ID to the topics type that would match the id I am trying to select in the .attr('checked', true) line.

Is there a way to programmatically select the checkboxes when an exact match of a term is searched?

Comment: Note: My answer below is more about how to recognize and use tag/categories in the query to automatically filter your results.

You should give more details about your implementation so that we can address the UI issue, which is to select the proper checkbox. But basically you'd do that in JavaScript without any PHP: when the response comes back from Algolia, look at which filter is selected and update the proper checkbox accordingly – your PHP code would not have knowledge of this at rendering time.

Comment: i added the query rule.  That seems to be working, I'm seeing the tags in my sidebar filtering.  Still not able to get the matching word selected.  How I tried to do is i add an ID to the topic and then I'm using the jquery code in a helper.on() function and a trigger("click") event to try and select the matching terms checkbox.  This works sometimes, but I can't get it to work reliably.

Comment: Do you think you could provide a simple jsfiddle showing that part of your page?

Comment: The site is in wordpress, i can DM a link?

Comment: I don't think you can DM here on SO.
If you don't want to share the URL publicly, send an email to support@algolia.com mentioning me and I can have a look!
We can then update this SO question accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I'm working at Algolia)

Algolia has actually released a feature recently that is exactly designed for what you want to do: [Query Rules](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/query-rules/query-rules-overview/)

With your tags, categories and topics set as attributes for faceting, you can ask the engine to automatically detect one of them in the query and activate the proper filtering for it as a result:

[image: adding a rule]

The condition is composed solely of a "facet placeholder" that will try to exactly match any value from the `categories` facet.

Note that I'm adding two consequences to my rule:

1. Filter on the identified `categories` facet value
2. Remove the word from the query

The second one will make sure your query still pulls up results by removing the facet value from it. Indeed once filtered on category-specific records, the word itself might not match anything anymore or create some "noise".
This is optional but I highly recommend it.

Note that this will **not** remove the word from the search box of your user so it will be transparent to them!